# How to getByRole a button with image in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

The best possible selector we can use in React Testing Library is `getByRole()`. This is good because we can select our node by it's role and accessibility name.

If we have a rendered component where we have multiple buttons - so I can't just use only `getByRole('button')` - and the button doesn't have text, meaning it doesn't have an accessible name, instead we have an image, how would I go about selecting that?

I know the image's accessible name derives from the `alt` attribute, and I am also aware I could use alternatives such as `data-testid`, however I would prefer to go with `getByRole` if there is a chance, so my tests resembles the way my software is used.

```
<Button onClick{() => void}>
 <img
  src={"foo"}
  alt={"alt text"}
/>
<Button/>
```

`getByRole('button')` will throw me an error as there will be multiple buttons on the wrapping component
`getAllByRole('button')` will return an array with all the buttons, however I only want the one with the image

I tried `getByRole('button', {name: "alt text"})` but this doesn't work, it kinda makes sense as it's a different node.

Any ideas if there is a logical way to get this using `getByRole` or I have to give up and resort to something like data-testid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best way that I know of to do this is by adding an `aria-label` to the button element. RTL will be able to query that as an accessible name with:

`getByRole('button', { name: /button-name/i })`

```
<Button aria-label="button-name" onClick{() => void}>
  <img
    src={"foo"}
    alt={"alt text"}
  />
<Button/>
```

Comment: AFAIK, aria-label is used for assistive technologies (e.g. screen readers). Is it really a good idea to put aria-label attributes just for testing while you don't actually care about assistive technologies?

Comment: @Hiroki you aren't loosing anything here by adding aria-label only for better

Answer (score 0):

You could select the corresponding button by `screen.getByAltText('alt text').parentNode`.

If it's only about firing a click event, you could directly use the img node -
`userEvent.click(screen.getByAltText('alt text'))`.

Hope this works for your case.

Comment: Would this not click the image, rather than the button? So the `<button>` is using the children props pattern with the `<img/>` as the children, if I simulate `click` on the element with the alt text, it will be expected that I simulate an `onClick` on the `<img/>` rather than the button.

`parentNode` would work, but at that point I could use a `data-testid` as well, because it won't resemble how the user is using the app anyway. When they do, they don't look for a parent node.

Comment: From my testing, simulating a click on the img will trigger the onClick function on the button tag.